# What is the Node structure of Boost list?

Tags: c++, list, boost

Looking [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/container/list.hpp) I can't understand what is the Node structure of Boost list? And not understanding this makes me difficult to understand why insertion is *(amortized) constant time* as it is mentioned in the code comments:

> A list is a doubly linked list. That is, it is a Sequence that
>   supports both //! forward and backward traversal, and (amortized)
>   constant time insertion and //! removal of elements at the beginning
>   or the end, or in the middle

Comment: When insert/removal, it operates on an `iterator`, which already points to the node in the insertion/removal position.
Then of course it can achieve constant time insertion/removal.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Are you familiar with the difference between constant time and amortized constant time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When insert/removal, it operates on an `iterator`, which already points to the node in the insertion/removal position.

Then of course it can achieve constant time insertion/removal.

---

Update: I do not know why it has "amortized" constant time, but you're asking about the internal node, here it is.

In `boost/container/list.hpp`, `list_node` is defined as:

```
template<class VoidPointer>
struct list_hook
{
   typedef typename container_detail::bi::make_list_base_hook
      <container_detail::bi::void_pointer<VoidPointer>, container_detail::bi::link_mode<container_detail::bi::normal_link> >::type type;
};

template <class T, class VoidPointer>
struct list_node
   :  public list_hook<VoidPointer>::type
{
...
}
```

It inherits `list_hook::type`, so let's see what it is.

In `intrusive/list_hook.hpp`:

```
template<class VoidPointer>
struct get_list_node_algo
{
   typedef circular_list_algorithms<list_node_traits<VoidPointer> > type;
};

struct make_list_base_hook
{
   ...
   typedef detail::generic_hook
   < get_list_node_algo<typename packed_options::void_pointer>
   , ...
   > implementation_defined;
   /// @endcond
   typedef implementation_defined type;
};
```

So it is a `generic_hook`, with `circular_list_algorithms<list_node_traits>` as the first template parameter:

```
template
   < class GetNodeAlgorithms
   ,...
   >
class generic_hook
   : ...
   , public make_node_holder<GetNodeAlgorithms, Tag, LinkMode, HookType>::type
```

It inherits `make_node_holder::type`, which is:

```
template
   < class GetNodeAlgorithms
   , class Tag
   , link_mode_type LinkMode
   , int HookType
   >
struct make_node_holder
{
   typedef typename detail::if_c
      <!detail::is_same<Tag, member_tag>::value
      , detail::node_holder
         < typename GetNodeAlgorithms::type::node
         , Tag
         , LinkMode
         , HookType>
      , typename GetNodeAlgorithms::type::node
      >::type type;
};
```

It is a `detail:node_holder` with type `GetNodeAlgorithms::type::node`:

```
template<class Node, class Tag, link_mode_type LinkMode, int>
struct node_holder
   :  public Node
{};
```

And here `GetNodeAlgorithms::type::node` is `list_node_traits::node` defined in `intrusive/detail/list_node.hpp`:

```
template<class VoidPointer>
struct list_node
{
   ...
   node_ptr next_;
   node_ptr prev_;
};

template<class VoidPointer>
struct list_node_traits
{
   typedef list_node<VoidPointer> node;
   ...
}
```

Now we see the `next_` and `prev_` pointer!

---

So in all, the inherits tree is:

```
list_node
-> list_hook::type
   -> make_list_base_hook::type 
      -> generic_hook::type
         -> make_node_holder::type
            -> node_holder
               -> Node
```

Where `Node`'s type is `boost::intrusive::list_node`, and it has **prev** and **next** pointer.

Comment: But you always provide `position` iterator to `insert` or `erase`. Then it is always O(1) **without amortized**, right? Also what about the Node structure? I don't see the left and right links.

Comment: Updated the answer about the node structure. But it's interesting why it ways **amortized** constant time, I'm curious too :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the Node explanation :)